# m2e and Maven profiles

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have setup a Maven profile following the advice on the [Maven Site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html)

```
<activeProfiles>
     <activeProfile>awayFromArchiva</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Now I can use this profile to stop errors during the build when Maven tries to download from an Archiva repository that is not available. I can compile on the command line successfully. Using the command line I get

```
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'xyz' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

during the successful build. A similar message is given in Eclipse but thrown as an error.

The profile does work as expected since the Archiva instance specified in my `settings.xml` for a different profile is ignored but the same goals produce very different results.

How can you ensure that `m2e` behaves the same as `mvn` on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse go to `Windows -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings` and change your user settings to point to your local `settings.xml` which your command prompt maven use.

Eclipse m2e uses embedded maven installation, you can point your eclipse to use your local maven installation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks The local settings.xml in my .m2 directory was already set correctly. I tried to change from the embedded to the local install in /usr/share/maven2 but it still doesn't work in Eclipse.